# BASH problem to fill a file 'til a determined size

Tags: bash, shell, rhel

I wrote a script to fill a file for some Disk capacity testing. Could you please tell me why I have an error?

```
#!/bin/bash 
COUNTER=0;
FILE_SIZE_BITS=8589934592;
FILE_NAME="fill_me";
while [ $COUNTER -eq 0 ]; do
    echo "Dummy text to fill the file" >> "$FILE_NAME";
    SIZE='stat -c%s fill_me';
    if [[ $SIZE -gt $FILE_SIZE_BITS ]]; then
        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1;
    fi
done
```

the error is:

```
-bash: [[: stat -c%s fill_me: division by 0 (error token is "fill_me")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is here:

```
SIZE='stat -c%s fill_me'
```

Do this instead:

```
SIZE=$(stat -c%s fill_me)
```

This sets SIZE to the output of the `stat -c%s fill_me` command. The `$(...)` syntax is the `Command Substitution` syntax:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.

---

BTW you can do the same thing with [`dd`<sup>*[manual]*</sup>](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=fill_me bs=1 count=8589934592
```

Comment: @ncohen: Do you really mean "bits", not "bytes"?  Other than that, +1, especially for the pointer to `dd`, which is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! @tripleee as far as I know, stat -c%s gives you bits...

Comment: So the count in `bs` is wrong, because it's in bytes. Easy to fix once you know.

Comment: @ncohen, from [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat): `%s: Total size, in **bytes**`

Comment: For efficiency, use a bigger block size in the `dd` command line.  I haven't tested recently, but on Linux a few years ago, the optimal value from a speed point of view was `bs=65536`.  You will need to divide the `count=` value accordingly.

Comment: @tripleee +1 (I set bs=1 in this answer for clarity)

Answer (score 2):

As amaud576875 answered, `dd` is the way to go.

For fun, here's another method:

```
str63=123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123
yes $str63 | head -134217728 > fill_me
```

Answer (score 0):

You found the programming error already, but from a shell programming point of view, the overall script is quite clunky.  Here is a refactored version.

```
#!/bin/bash 
FILE_SIZE_BITS=8589934592;
FILE_NAME="fill_me";
while true; do
    echo "Dummy text to fill the file" >> "$FILE_NAME";
    SIZE=$(stat -c%s "$FILE_NAME")  # if you have a variable, use it everywhere
    if [[ $SIZE -gt $FILE_SIZE_BITS ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

The variable name `COUNT` and the arithmetic you performed on it is rather misleading, as you exit as soon as COUNT is bigger than 0.  Might as well use a true/false flag in that case, but here, I don't even store the status in a variable.  Instead, I `break` out of the loop (and thus, the entire script) when the exit condition is true.